# Setting UIAlertView delegate

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying fro viewcontroller A to se a delegate to a UIAlertView in viewcontroller B using this code:

In ViewcontrollerA.m

```
-(IBAction)callCancelAlert:(id)sender{

ViewcontrollerB *controller = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                      delegate: PhotoViewController
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
//[alert release];
}
```

and #import ViewcontorllerB.h

...but I get the error "Unexpected interface name ViewcontorllerB: expected expression". What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate needs to be the instance of ViewControllerB, not the class.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                      delegate: PhotoViewController
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

to

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                      message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                      delegate: controller
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: ok, I tried this and as soon as I press a button on the UIAlertView I get this error: 0x3a61a5b6:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8] and the app crashes

Comment: You set the delegate to an object that is going to get garbage collected as soon as the method ends. Thus, by the time the user presses a button and the UIAlertView tries to call the delegate, it's using a delegate pointer that is now pointing at random memory. If you're going to set a delegate object, you have to make sure that delegate object is retained/held somewhere permanent. The alert's "show" method effectively fires it off in the background, and your method continues on executing whatever code follows the show method immediately (causing your created delegate object to get released).

Comment: I thought instead of using init, using retain, but I am in ARC

Comment: What is the relation between PhotoViewController and ViewcontrollerB? Setting up your delegate should probably look like this: ViewcontrollerB *controller = [[ViewcontrollerB alloc] init]; Also, to see what might be causing the crash what have you implemented in alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: on the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't mean `delegate: PhotoViewController`, which means "set the delegate to the PhotoViewController class".

Instead, you likely want this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                  initWithTitle: @"Announcement"
                  message: @"It turns out that you are playing Addicus!"
                  delegate:controller
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
```